# Expected number of transitions in a binary sequence

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains

Consider a randomly generated (iid) binary sequence of length $N$. What is the expected number of transitions in that sequence?

A transition occurs when a bit changes from $0$ to $1$ or from $1$ to $0$.

For example, consider the following binary sequence of length $5$.

$$10010$$

There are 3 transitions in the above sequence.

Comment: If you're assuming that each bit is $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$ each, this needs to be stated explicitly.

Comment: If that's the case, then you can proceed by generating a $N-1$ bit sequence, in which the $k$th bit is $0$ if the $k$th and $k+1$th bits of the original sequence are the same, and $1$ if they're different.  Show that this derived sequence also consists of bits that are independently $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$ each, and figure out the expected number of $1$'s in the derived sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $N-1$ adjacent pairs of bits, and each pair is a transition with probability $\frac12$ (or, in general, with probability $2p(1-p)$, where $p$ is the probability of a $1$), so the expected number of transitions is $\frac{N-1}{2}$.

In the case where $p = \frac12$, the distribution is binomial; in general, it's not, because adjacent transitions are not independent. (Imagine $p=0.01$; then any transition from $0$ to $1$ is overwhelmingly likely to be followed by a transition back to $0$.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the probability of 0 and 1 is equal, and the sequence is memory-less, then the average number of transitions will be (n-1)/2. For each transition for one bit to the next the probability of the next bit being different from the current bit is 1/2, and therefore it counts as 1/2 the transition. For n bits you have (n-1) possible transitions, with a probability of 1/2 for each.